# PHP call-time pass-by-reference show no E_DEPRECATED

Tags: php, reference, porting

According to [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), **E_DEPRECATED** will be throw when you use the **"call-time pass-by-reference"**

However, when I run the following code in command line, there is no error or any warning.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo PHP_VERSION, "\n"; // print 5.3.10-1ubuntu2ppa6~lucid

function test($string)
{
    $string = 'bar';
}

$a = 'foo';
test(&$a);
echo $a; // print bar
```

Comment: Check your php.ini. Is your error reporting on?

Comment: Yes you are right, so if I cannot change the php.ini, I can't force it anyway?

Comment: @Ryan: On the commandline you can specify your own php.ini path and/or just set ini directives with the `-d` switch (works as well multiple times): http://www.php.net/features.commandline.options

Answer (score 3):

The error message is a compile-time error. You are setting the error_reporting level at runtime using the `error_reporting()` function which is executed after the error was already produced.

Best thing is to set the `error_level` in  `php.ini`. If you can't do that this means you should setup a local development environment as this error level shoud not be shown on a production system.

What will also work is to split it up in multiple file, somethling like

a.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
include 'b.php';
?>
```

b.php:

```
<?php
/* ... */ 
test(&a);
/*... */
?>
```

Since then the `error_reporting` in a.php will be executed before b.php is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

because `allow_call_time_pass_reference` set to `true` in your php.ini file. set to `false` to get the error.

EDIT: Yes , you right, i checked with V5.2.9 and it throws warning and it should be at V5.3.x according document but it does not. seems it's a bug

Comment: This is not firsthand an answer but a guess. And when I read the feedback by Ryan your guess was wrong :(

Comment: Yes I see but I don't understand the edit. What do you think exactly is a bug? And in which software should that bug be located?

Comment: @hakre, PHP 5.3.x should be  E_DEPRECATED as a result of OP's example. it should throws a warning about calling by reference, but it doesn't, regardless `allow_call_time_pass_reference` is `on` or `off`.
I tested with PHP 5.2.9 and it works true and throws the warning. So it should be a bug in PHP 5.3.X

Comment: I still have problems to follow, sorry. So what you say is that the error-reporting behaviour differs between PHP 5.2 and 5.3? And you consider that a bug?

Comment: Yes,when PHP claims it should throws warning and it does not, in my view, it is a bug.

Comment: Well also the claim could be wrong. Then it's a documentation inaccuracy :) But I just wanted to understand what you mean, thanks a lot for the clarification. But the OP commented that enabling error reporting did show the correct E_DEPRECATED. And that was what I originally was concerned about, you guessed not that it was disabled error display, but just assumed a different setting. Maybe that explains your bug assumption?

Comment: No, i think the OP did not accept showing correct E_DEPRECATED. he just confirm if he could enabled `display_errors` in `php.ini` , it probably show correct E_DEPRECATED. But i checked with `display_errors` enabled with both versions and confirm it does not show correct E_DEPRECATED in 5.3.6

Comment: 5.3.6 gives an `E_DEPRECATED` error. It actually is the only version where you can error-handle this. Below 5.3 PHP gives a `E_COMPILE_WARNING` you can only log and since PHP 5.4 it is `E_ERROR` (fatal error). I do not see any conflicting material on the manual. Compare with: http://3v4l.org/Se5cH - You probably have a specifically crafted PHP version?

Comment: many thanks for the useful link.it is so strange.it does not work on my local PHP 5.3.6

Comment: Which OS/PHP are you using? (Yes, it's kinda strange but maybe there is a simple explanation for it in the end :) )

Comment: It is apache 2.2 on windows

Comment: Why are you not upgrading PHP 5.3 then to the latest stable? Just asking, but that might remove that problem (and you might find out that with the apache server you're using a different PHP version?)

Comment: Actually active version is 5.2.9 and i have extra 5.3.6 for testing. My web service provider have 5.2.9 and i have to use it :)
But, OMG, it seems your prediction is going to be truth. I found the problem. default value for error reporting in PHP 5.2.9 is `E_ALL` and i thought it is the same for PHP 5.3.6 , but default is `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`. this a is real simple end. it was my fault ...sorry :)

Comment: Well at least you were able to spot it in the end, that is most important :)